# Handle WorkerLostError in celery after SIGSEGV

Tags: python, celery

I have a situation, where my workers get killed by SIGSEGV from time to time due to a low quality C/C++ dependency. In these cases, I need to know which tasks have failed. Is there a way to react to the resulting WorkerLostError and get to know which task (e.g. by taks_id) caused the worker loss? Any other way to realize that a certain tasks failed due to SIGSEGV?

Thx

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution that works for me. First I set my task to `acks_late=True`, allowing them to be retried when not completed. But, celery deliberately avoids retries after segfaults to prevent infinite message loops. I disabled this feature with `task_reject_on_worker_lost=True`. Now, after segfault, the task gets run again with the same `task_id` and I can detect that a properly fail the task on the second run.

Another solution, without the dangerous `task_reject_on_worker_lost=True`, is a custom request and task class ([celery docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#requests-and-custom-requests)). The `on_failure` is run in the workers main thread and will be called on the `WorkerLostError`. The `on_failure` callback on the task is self (which is called by the lost child) will not be called.

Comment: How to re-execute the failed task inside `on_failure` callback?

Comment: How to re-execute the task failed due to `WorkerLostError` inside custom request's `on_failure` callback?